Can I generate Crashlytics report from C++?
How can I generate Crashlytics report from C++ code?
There is only log a method on C++ api
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/main/firebase-crashlytics-ndk/src/main/jni/libcrashlytics/include/crashlytics/external/crashlytics.h
I write jni wrapper for call crashlytics.recordException(Exception(message)), but this way C++ stacktrace is missing on firebase dashboard, it shows only java stack with one frame.
